# How come local storage only returns undefined and not what the user inputs in the text area?

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I am having trouble figuring out why in my code it will not return what the user inputs in the text area when the page gets refreshed. If in the text area, the user puts a task like 'morning run' and then hits the save button, 'morning run' appears fine but as soon as I refresh the page, it erases. I've been struggling with the Local Storage, something I can't seem to figure out Thanks for any help. Here is my code:

```
function getLocalStorage(key) {
    let value = localStorage.getItem(key);
    if (value) {
        $(`#text${key}`).text(value);
    }
}

function dayPlanner() {
    for (let i = 9; i < 18; i++) {

        $('.container').append($(`<div data-time=${i} id='${i}'>`));
        $('.container').append($('<div class="col-sm-2"> <p class="workHour">' + timeDisplay(i) + '</p>'));
        $('.container').append($(`<div class="col-sm-8"> <textarea class= "userInput" id=text${i} placeholder="Add your event here..."></textarea>`));
        $('.container').append($(`<div class="col-sm-2"><button class="saveBtn" id=${i}><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>`));

        getLocalStorage(i)
    }
}

dayPlanner();

var saveBtn = $('.saveBtn');

saveBtn.on('click', function(){
    let eventId = $(this).attr('id');
    let eventText = $('.userInput').val();
    localStorage.setItem(eventId, eventText);
    console.log('button clicked');
});
```

Comment: IDs must be unique to the document. You have it as the id of both the first `div` and the `button`. Note that because you use `$()` around the HTML you are appending, and because you `append` multiple times, the first `div` you append is empty. Also, while HTML5 has relaxed the requirements for ids, it's generally best to avoid all-numerical ids for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ok so I changed the 'id='${i}' to a class now for both the 'div' and the 'button'. Are you also saying there is an issue with the 'id=text${i}' in the 'textarea'?